# I was going to you?

Tags: sentence-usage

I just want to ask if I was planning to go to someone and in the same minute he show up what is the suitable thing to say?
Is it I was going to you?
Thank you..

Comment: What do you mean: going to you? To their office, house, etc. Going to see a person? "going to you" has a more restricted meaning.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the construction "going to (verb)", meaning "planning to (verb)" and the verb "to go", meaning "to travel".  It is possible to say "I was planning to go to you", though, meaning "I was planning to travel to you."

Comment: Yes I meant going to her office and she showed up before I go

Answer (score 1):

You would simply say

> I was ***just*** going to **see** you.

using "***just***" indicates *in the same moment* they arrived.  If someone calls you that you were about to call, you would say

> I was ***just*** about to call you.

but you need to mention what you were about to do.

You could also say

> I was just about to go to you.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these could work:

- I was just going to try and find you!
- I was just leaving to go look for you.
- I was on my way to come see you.
- I was about to head your way.

  (several other variants might work fine, too)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have asked a friend who is very good at math for help with a calculus problem.  It is your intention to stop by her library carrel, since you don't want to inconvenience her by also asking her to come to you. But she shows up at *your* library carrel. Then you might say,

> Thanks so much for dropping by. I was going to come to you.  I didn't mean for you to have to come to me.

**going** and **coming** are usually deictic, expressing the *speaker's* point of view, but that point-of-view can be reversed in situations where politeness and deference come into play, for example.

Comment: Yes, but there's also: "I was going to come to you with the problem." where the entire thing is dealt with by phone. That's why i asked her to clarify.

Comment: there **going to come to you** means **intending to come to you**.